# Why df.apply() doesn't change the df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a simple function to my pandas dataframe, but since if was not working, I replaced it with an even simpler function which returns element * 2.
When I run a program, it doesn't do anything to my df.
This is the code and the output is below:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
def to_pct(element):
    # element1 = f":.2f".format(element)
    # new_elem1 = str(element1)
    # new_elem2 = new_elem1 + "%"
    # return new_elem2
    elem = 2*element
    return elem
print(df.head())
df.apply(to_pct,axis=0)
#df = to_pct(df)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
         GE      MSFT       JNJ         K        BA       IBM
1  0.564447 -0.015038  0.060104 -0.097915  0.587312  0.215139
2  0.182322  0.332134  0.415599  0.074572 -0.002378  0.060383
3  0.569322  0.442803  0.577138  0.377610  0.655544  0.273251
4  0.428678  0.791151  0.229403 -0.050876  0.543416  0.410840
5  0.471113  0.380364  0.176234  0.320396  0.371143  0.026292
         GE      MSFT       JNJ         K        BA       IBM
1  0.564447 -0.015038  0.060104 -0.097915  0.587312  0.215139
2  0.182322  0.332134  0.415599  0.074572 -0.002378  0.060383
3  0.569322  0.442803  0.577138  0.377610  0.655544  0.273251
4  0.428678  0.791151  0.229403 -0.050876  0.543416  0.410840
5  0.471113  0.380364  0.176234  0.320396  0.371143  0.026292
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  The `apply` documentation is clear on the result: it returns an altered series; it does not edit the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reassign the new DataFrame to `df`.

`df = df.apply(to_pct,axis=0)`

Comment: Thanks, i bet i tried that some time ago and it didn't work, but it's probably not the case and I'm going crazy lol Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame.apply returns a dataframe, it doesn't alter the dataframe it's 'applied' to.

See here [pd.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

So assign the result of apply to the original dataframe.

```
df = df.apply(to_pct,axis=0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer